# C# BackgroundProcess: is it safe to use .CancelAsync before .RunworkerAsync?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

When the user tries to double click **button**, the *backgroundWorker* will initiate twice.

is this a good workaround?

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Some processing here
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    button1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { button1.Enabled= true; });
}

// Run backgroundProcess
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.button1.Enabled = false;
    backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: As per my opinion, You should make enable/Disable button. Enable in default state. As you click on the button, it will disabled and only enabled when 1. Process is complete. 2. Process is cancelled 3. catch any error into process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) event to enable button1. instead for enabling then in `backgroundWorker1_DoWork`

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           this.button1.Enabled = true;
            //rest of operations
        }
```

What is wrong with your code:

You ware enabling the button in `_DoWork` that is meaning less since `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAssync();` will call `_DoWork()` there the button enables and hence the second click also get executed.

Comment: I've forgot to mention that I used `button1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { button1.Enabled= true; });` which can be use inside the `_DoWork`. :)

Comment: Have you tried the solution that i have suggested? also you can try `button1.Invoke(..` in `_RunWorkerCompleted` it should work

Answer (score 0):

You have to take care of three basic things when you are going to use BackgrounWorker.

1. DoWork:  You can handle execution of your business logic and cancellation of your work if required.
2. RunWorkerCompleted: You can handle post execution task. Here you want to enable button, so you should write appropriate code into RunWorkerCompleted Event.
3. Handle the WorkerSupportsCancellation property if you want to cancel backgroundworker process at any point of execution.

   ```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;            
       backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
       backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
       button1.Enabled = false;
       backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
   }

   void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
       button1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { button1.Enabled = true; });
       backgroundWorker1.DoWork -= backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
       backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted -= backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
   }

   void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
       {
           Thread.Sleep(1000);                
           AppendTextBox( "Hit: " + i.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
           if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
           {
               break;
           }

       }
       if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
       {
           e.Cancel = true;
       }            
   }
   public void AppendTextBox(string value)
   {
       if (InvokeRequired)
       {
           this.Invoke(new Action<string>(AppendTextBox), new object[] { value });
           return;
       }
       textBox1.Text += value;
   }
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
           backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync(); 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If the worker is actually running, then almost certainly not.

Cancellation is cooperative. Calling `CancelAsync` just sets the `CancellationPending` flag to true. It is up to the background worker to periodically check this flag and respond to cancellation.

The chances that a running worker has gotten to an appropriate point to check that flag, checked it, and responded, all within the gap of time between these two lines of code:

```
backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Is extremely slim. It's more likely (if the worker was running) that `RunWorkerAsync` will throw `InvalidOperationException` since the worker is still running.